# Laravel scope with union

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I need a way to sort my models by two columns (but not as order by x, y does). I have a `priority` column that can 'boost' a model in results, and standard `created_at` that should be sorting key when `priority` is not set. The only way I have found to do this was with unions.

With query like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM `charts` WHERE priority IS NOT NULL ORDER BY priority ASC) 
UNION (SELECT * FROM `charts` WHERE priority IS NULL AND created_at IS NOT NULL ORDER BY CREATED_AT ASC) 
UNION (SELECT * FROM `charts` WHERE created_at IS NULL)
```

So I tried to do something like:

```
public function scopeSortPriority($query)
{
    return $query->whereNotNull('priority')
        ->orderBy('priority')
        ->union($query->whereNull('priority')
            ->whereNotNull('created_at')
            ->orderBy('created_at'))
        ->union($query->whereNull('priority')
            ->whereNull('created_at'));
}
```

But it sadly does not work.

Is there an other way to accomplish what I want in SQL? Otherwise - how should I rebuild this scope to make it work?

Comment: I suggest you set a priority to all models (even if that is just 0 for most) that way you can order by `priority desc, created_at` e.g. priority first and then created at if priority is the same.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using `$query` in your unions.

If you know that the common part of your query and your unions allways will be `\DB::table('charts')` you can do:

```
$query->whereNotNull('priority')
    ->orderBy('priority')
    ->union(\DB::table('charts')->whereNull('priority')
        ->whereNotNull('created_at')
        ->orderBy('created_at'))
    ->union(\DB::table('charts')->whereNull('priority')
        ->whereNull('created_at'));
```

If `$query` will be the same but can change you can do:

```
    $query2 = clone $query;
    $query3 = clone $query;

    $query->whereNotNull('priority')
    ->orderBy('priority')
    ->union($query2->whereNull('priority')
        ->whereNotNull('created_at')
        ->orderBy('created_at'))
    ->union($query3->whereNull('priority')
        ->whereNull('created_at'));
```

In both case the output of the sql is:

```
(select * from `charts` where `priority` is not null order by `priority` asc) union (select * from `charts` where `priority` is null and `created_at` is not null order by `created_at` asc) union (select * from `charts` where `priority` is null and `created_at` is null)
```